# SQLite manually set column with insert from a SELECT

Tags: sqlite, etl

I need to create a ban list in my DB. Before you ask, no it's not actually for books, banning books is dumb. To do this, I'm selecting based on criteria already in the table and I'm inserting straight into the Bans table. The problem is, I want to include a manual string for the reason for the ban. I've included some sample data below and the SQL I'm using currently.

## Sample Data:

### Books

```
ID  | Author             | Title
1   | Mark Twain         | Huckleberry Fin
2   | Stephen King       | IT
3   | Mark Twain         | Tom Sawyer
4   | Stephen King       | Carrie
5   | William Shakespeare| Hamlet
6   | Stephen King       | The Stand
7   | Ernest Hemingway   | The Old Man and the Sea
8   | JK Rowling         | Harry Potter
9   | Ernest Hemingway   | For Whom the Bell Tolls
10  | William Shakespeare| Othello
11  | Ernest Hemingway   | A Farewell to Arms
12  | William Shakespeare| Richard III
13  | JK Rowling         | Fantastic Beasts and where to find them
```

### Bans

```
ID  | Reason
8   | Magic & Stuff
13  | Magic & Stuff
```

## Current Query:

```
 INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Bans SELECT ID FROM Books 
 WHERE Author = "Stephen King"
```

This query will put all the IDs for Stephan Kings books into the bans table. But, I'd like to be able to assign a reason that they were banned.

## Result Of Current Query:

### Bans

```
ID  | Reason
8   | Magic & Stuff
13  | Magic & Stuff
2   |
4   |
6   |
```

## Desired Result Of Current Query:

What I want to be able to do is have a query that will allow me to give a reason as well. So I end up with this instead

### Bans

```
ID  | Reason
8   | Magic & Stuff
13  | Magic & Stuff
2   | Too Scary For Kids
4   | Too Scary For Kids
6   | Too Scary For Kids
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Bans 
    SELECT ID, "Too Scary For Kids" FROM Books WHERE Author = "Stephen King"
```

Comment: Dang it, too simple. How does SQLite know that "Too Scary For Kids" is for the reason column and not some other? Like if the Bans Structure was, ID, Reason and BannedOnWhosAuth. How would SQLite know the string was for Reason and not BannedOnWhosAuth?

Comment: You have two columns, `ID` and `Reasons`. This query inserts two fields, in the same order. This is how SQL engine "knows" it. To ensure that you are inserting the right fields, you can use this: `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Bans (ID, Reason) SELECT.....`

Comment: Awesome! So, just so I fully understand, if I wanted to use that same structure, but give no reason I could do: INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Bans (ID, BannedOnWhosAuth) SELECT ID, "Rick" FROM Books WHERE Author = "Stephen King"   Is that right?

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it Michael!